# Deza-Frankl-Singhi theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $A$ b a system of $(2p-1)$ element subsets of of an $n$-element set such that no two sets in $A$ intersect in precisely $p-1$ elements. I would like to prove that

$$|A|\leq \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{n \choose k}. $$

I feel that the Deza-Frankl-Singhi theorem could be applied to prove this but I am not sure how.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I revised the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case of the Frankl-Wilson Theorem(see e.g. Section 3.2, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.03217.pdf)

> If $L$ is a family of residuals modulo $p$ of size $s$, $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of subsets of $[n]$ such that $|A| \notin L$ and $|A \cap B| \in L$ for all $A\neq B \in \mathcal{F}$, then
> $$|\mathcal{F}| \leq \sum_{i \leq s} \binom{n}{i}.$$

Apply the theorem to $L = \{n: n \equiv 0,1,\cdots, p - 2 \bmod{p}\}$.

Comment: Thank you Shengtong. I am not sure how this follows from the Frankl-Wilson Theorem. Could you please elaborate a bit further?

Comment: This follows by taking $L$ be the all residuals modulo $p$ aside from $p - 1$.

Comment: Are you using the version of the Theorem written in the answer of the post? I still don't see how you obtain it from that theorem. I am particularly confused about $\lambda_s$.

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be many equivalent forms of Frankl-Wilson. I'm using Frankl-Wilson as in Section 3.2 of this paper. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.03217.pdf. In the form I stated in the response

Comment: Can't $L$ be a number bigger than $p$ as the sets have $(2p-1)$ elements? For instance we can have two sets $A,B$ such that $|A\cap B|=p+1$. Why we sum only up to $p-1$?

Comment: $L$ is a set of **residual classes** modulo $p$. For example, here $L$ consists of every integer that has remainder $0,1,\cdots, p - 2$ modulo $p$. Then $0,1,\cdots, p - 2, p, p + 1, \cdots, 2p - 2$ lies in $L$, but $p - 1, 2p - 1$ doesn't. $s = p - 1$ since there are exactly $p - 1$ residual classes in $L$.

Comment: This makes sense now. Thank you so much.